# Finding last column across multiple sheets in a function

Tags: vba, excel

I have to run a loop in multiple sheets by getting the last column for each sheet. How can I get the last column of every sheet? I tried putting this a function. Can you please suggest on this as I am just a beginner on this.

Update:
Its working fine now. Tried the code provided by @sktneer. Thanks everyone for your inputs.

Comment: Isn't `ws` your sheet? Are you passing it to your function?

Comment: Could we have a look at your code please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Sub LastColumnInEachSheet()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lc As Long

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    lc = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
    Debug.Print ws.Name, lc
Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: This is good. Thanks a lot...Can you please tell me if there are 2 tables in a single sheet, and I want to find the last column of each table, then how can I proceed with it? As the last column no is shown for the last column which has the data..but in my tables, the first table which is above has last column no less than the below table.

Comment: You're welcome! I would suggest you to open a new question with all the details like are there inbuilt excel tables on each sheet etc. It would be better if you can share a screenshot of the sheet to visualize the actual layout of data.

Comment: This is the link for my new question. Request you to please provide your input. Thanks in advance. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49432097/last-column-of-a-line/49432390#49432390]

Answer (score 1):

Below code will go through all worksheets in the workbook:

```
Dim oWS As Worksheet

For Each oWS In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    oWS.Name   ' Give you the sheet name
    oWS.Cells(1, oWS.Columns.count).End(xlToLeft).Column   ' Gives you total columns in a sheet
Next
```