# Last column of a specific row in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I have to find the last column of a row in a sheet. I am able to find the last column in the sheet, but for a particular row, I need to find the last column which will vary for every sheet in the excel, and it will vary at every run. To find the last column, I have used the below code, with reference from the question [Finding last column across multiple sheets in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49428994/how-to-find-last-column-across-multiple-sheets-in-a-function):

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
 lc = ws.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByColumns,      
 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
 Debug.Print ws.Name, lc
 MsgBox lc
 Next ws
```

Updated:
Trying to use the below code, but its showing error code 91. Function is :

```
 Function lastColumn(Optional sheetName As String, Optional 
rowToCheck  As Long =  1) As Long

Dim ws  As Worksheet

If sheetName = vbNullString Then
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
Else
    Set ws = Worksheets(sheetName)
End If

lastColumn = ws.Cells(rowToCheck, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Function
```

Calling it in the code as:

```
For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

    i = ws.Columns(2).Find("Total").Row (error code as 91)
    Debug.Print lastColumn(ws.Name, i)
Next ws
```

Comment: Use `ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column` where `i` = the number of the row.

Comment: Error 91 means it didn't find the word "Total" in column B of the sheet you checked.  Are certain every single sheet has a cell with "Total" in it somewhere in column B?  You may need to add a check to make sure it's being found properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub Test()

For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
    lc = ws.Cells(i, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Debug.Print ws.Name, lc
    MsgBox lc
Next ws

End Sub
```

Just replace `i` with the row number.

Answer (score 1):

This is the function that I am using for lastColumn per specific row:

```
Function lastColumn(Optional sheetName As String, Optional rowToCheck As Long = 1) As Long

    Dim ws  As Worksheet

    If sheetName = vbNullString Then
        Set ws = ActiveSheet
    Else
        Set ws = Worksheets(sheetName)
    End If

    lastColumn = ws.Cells(rowToCheck, ws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

End Function
```

It takes optional arguments `sheetName` and `rowToCheck`. This is a way to run it for your case:

```
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim ws      As Worksheet
    Dim lc      As Long
    lc  = 8

    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        Debug.Print lastColumn(ws.Name, lc)
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: This gives the last column number in the sheet, but I need the last column number of a line. This I have already tried, but each sheet has a different row number whose last column number has to be found out.

Comment: @user9351236 - what is a line? A row?

Comment: @user9351236 - and based on what it will vary?

Comment: The data is different in each sheet...so the count of the row number will be different for each sheet..

Comment: @user9351236 - so you are looking for the last column of the last row per sheet?

Comment: No...I am getting the row number of each sheet by finding the text "Total" in it..And once I get the row number which has "Total" text in it, then I find out the last column number of that row (or line)...

Comment: @user9351236 - so it should be easy. Just replace `lc` with the row on which you have found the text "Total". If you are using `.Find` and assigning to a cell, then it should be `cell.Row` instead of `lc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
With Worksheets(set_sheet_name)
    LastCol = .Cells(5, .Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
End With
```

this will get you nr. of columns from the line "5", if you want another line just change the 5 with whatever line you need.